Understanding linearity of Maxwell's equation compared to non-linarity of GR
In this post, it is mentioned that a linear equation means that the solutions 'do not interact with each other' or 'do not know' about each other. But we know that Maxwell's equations are linear equations and therefore obey the principle of superposition: $\vec{E} = \vec{E_1} + \vec{E_2}$. But if we have two charges, then clearly the charges are interacting together? The electric field that one charge produces influences the movement of another charge, which changes the total electric field. So this is a clear example of interaction between the solutions. But the equation is still linear, since the total electric field is still given by the sum of both electric fields, however they are interacting.
If you compare this with GR, then the solution is self-interacting: a mass produces a curvature, which tells the mass how to move, which influences the curvature etc. However, why would that automatically guarantee it is a non-linear equation? If I add another mass, why is it not, in principle, possible that the solution is a sum of two (self)interacting solutions? Just like in the Maxwell case above (I know that the GR equations are actually non-linear).

There are 10 numbers that must be known for every point in GR. Suppose there is a busy ocean full of waves and objects, then these 10 numbers seem to be describing the rate of change of density at every point in this ocean, as well as how this density change over time. Armed with this divinely complete set of information, it is of course possible to reconstruct every wave in this ocean from past to future... But tabulating all this information before proceeding is usually a Herculean task in practice, even for a tiny pond, which seems why no one could calculate any realistic metric in GR.

... furthermore this metric density is not actually measuring the matter and radiation density $T_{\mu\nu}$ on the RHS. At locations with zero $T_{\mu\nu}$, the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ is still not zero, thus there is something there not seeable, call it curvature or not.

RE: "The electric field that one charge produces influences the movement of another charge," this effect is not part of Maxwell's equations. Maxwell's equations say nothing about how charged particles move in the presence of EM fields.

Superposition is not interaction. Two classical light beams pass right through each other.

This is a good question because it points out thing people say ("Maxwell's equations are linear") which is true but can be easily interpreted incorrectly.
First, just to clarify, a set of differential equations for functions $F_i(\vec{x}, t)$ are linear if they have the form
$$
\sum_j \hat{D}_{ij}(\vec{x}, t) F_j(\vec{x}, t) = J_i(\vec{x}, t)
$$
where $\hat{D}_{ij}(x)$ is some set of differential operators that can depend on $\vec{x}$ and $t$ but not on $F$, and $J_i$ is a set of known functions. If $J_i=0$, this implies the superposition principle, that if $F_i(\vec{x}, t)$ and $G_i(\vec{x}, t)$ are solutions, then so is $a F_i + b G_i$ for constants $a$ and $b$. If $J_i$ is non-zero, then there's still a version of superposition; if $F_i$ is a solution for source $J_i$, and $G_i$ is a solution for source $K_i$, then $F_i+G_i$ is a solution with source $J_i+K_i$.
For fixed charge density $\rho(\vec{x}, t)$ and current density $\vec{J}(\vec{x}, t)$, Maxwell's equations are linear differential equations for the electric field $\vec{E}$ and magnetic field $\vec{B}$ (provided the charge density and current density obey the continuity equation, $\partial_t \rho + \nabla \cdot \vec{J}=0$, otherwise the equations aren't consistent).
However, if you want to include the dynamics of charges and currents, then the resulting equations aren't linear in general. The term "Maxwell's equations" usually does not refer to this situation, it refers to the situation where the charges and currents are known, or maybe when they obey linear constitutive equations. However, this won't be the case if you have a bunch of electrons, and you want to see how they interact. You have given a good physical argument for why electrons coupled to the electromagnetic field can't be a linear system. An electron at rest produces a static field, whereas two electrons will repel, and two electrons repelling each other is clearly not a superposition of two static electrons.
The theory that describes electrons coupled to the electromagnetic field is usually studied in quantum field theory and is called quantum electrodynamics. If you worked out its equations of motion, you would find they are not linear.
You don't need to go to QED to see where the problem is, though. Just looking at the force between that point charge of charge $q_2$ at position $r_1$ exerts on a point charge of charge $q_1$ and position $\vec{r}_1$ (please double check me on the sign)
$$
\vec{F}_1 = k q_1 q_2 \frac{\vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2}{|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|^3}
$$
you can see that the differential equation $\vec{F}_1=m\ddot{\vec{r}}_1$ for particle $1$ will be non-linear in $\vec{r}_1(t)$.
Even Newtonian gravity has this type of non-linearity. In other words, Newtonian gravity is a linear differential equation for the Newtonian potential $\phi$ if the masses are known, but if you want to see how the masses plus the gravitational potential evolve, then you have a non-linear set of equations. (As an aside, the fact that Newtonian gravity with dynamical point masses is non-linear is the reason the famous three body problem is so hard!)
General Relativity, however, has an even deeper kind of non-linearity. Even if there was no matter at all, the equations would still be non-linear. This is not true of Maxwell's equations -- if $\rho=J=0$, then the equations for $E$ and $B$ are linear -- nor of Newtonian gravity -- if the mass is zero, then the gravitational force is zero. Einstein's equations, however, are non-linear in the metric tensor even when the stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}=0$. This is why GR is able to have non-trivial vacuum solutions, called black holes! An observer can experience gravitation in GR, even if the stress-energy tensor vanishes everywhere in the spacetime! One (somewhat sloppy) way to say it is that the gravitational field can act as its own source, because of the non-linearity -- gravity gravitates!

So Maxwell's equations actually don't know about dynamics of charges and currents? (i.e. that the charges will move, only using Maxwell's equations). So any time you assume a fixed charge density, you assume that there are no interactions between them?

@Stallmp Right, if you want to know about the backreaction of the fields on the charges and currents, you will end up with a non-linear set of equations in general, and you won't have pure Maxwell's equations (similar to how the equations for QED are not Maxwell's equations because they include the interaction between the electron and the photon).

Thanks a lot! I was still wondering regarding the GR case: because of its non-linearity, it is able to have a non-trivial solution even though the stress-energy tensor vanishes everywhere, which you can interpret as the gravitational field acting as its own source. Is there a more precise way to formulate in words/conceptually how a vanishing stress-energy tensor can still produce a non-zero curvature?

The mathematical answer is that when $T_{\mu\nu}=0$, the Einstein equations become $R_{\mu\nu}=0$, where $R_{\mu\nu}$ is the Ricci tensor. You can check explicitly that the Schwarzschild metric (for example) has $R_{\mu\nu}=0$, but non-zero curvature. One way to see that this is possible is that the Ricci tensor has $10$ independent components in four spacetime dimensions, but the full Riemann tensor that describes the curvature has $21$, so the Einstein equations don't impose full flatness on the metric in the absence of matter. (...)

(...) To use a bit less differential geometry, it's kind of a generic feature of equations that non-linear terms allow you to have non-trivial solutions with no source. Here's an analogy just using polymials. A linear equation would look like $A x = J$. If $J=0$, then the only solution is $x=0$. But if we had $A x^2 + B x = J$, then even if $J=0$ we could have $x=\sqrt{-B/A}$.

Thank you so much Andrew!

@Stallmp Incidentally, the argument I gave above about there being $10$ Einstein equations but $21$ curvature components actually is independent of whether or not $T_{\mu\nu}=0$. The extra components form the so-called Weyl tensor, and physically you could think of the existence of the Weyl tensor as due to gravitational waves (which can propagate even without matter). The Schwarzschild metric really comes because there are non-trivial static solutions to $R_{\mu\nu}=0$, which is somewhat analogous to the polynomial example.

So is it correct to say that the Riemann tensor is composed of the Weyl tensor and the Ricci tensor together? So the Weyl tensor are the components which are not included in the Ricci tensor?

@Stallmp Yep, if you read the wikipedia article: "This tensor has the same symmetries as the Riemann tensor, but satisfies the extra condition that it is trace-free: metric contraction on any pair of indices yields zero. It is obtained from the Riemann tensor by subtracting a tensor that is a linear expression in the Ricci tensor." :)

The Einstein field equations are nonlinear because they satisfy the mathematical definition of nonlinearity, whereas the Maxwell equations satisfy the definition of linearity. The properties of the gravitational and electric fields follow from the properties of the equations, not vice versa.
In the GR case, if you make the perturbation to the flat-spacetime metric small enough that higher-order terms fall out, you can linearize the equations and obtain something similar to Maxwell's. However, when the perturbation is large, second- or even higher-order terms become significant and cannot be easily corrected for.

Yes I understand that, but my question is basically about the link between solutions (self) interacting and the linearity or non linearity of the equations. It seems to be an if and only if statement that a self interacting solution guarantees a non linear equation.
